# Export SharePoint Search Results and List View to Excel

Tags: search, sharepoint-foundation, excel, export

Can we export SharePoint Search Result to Excel? Note that our client is using SharePoint Foundation 2010.

I have searched the web and found a free tool that does this but unfortunately it works only for SharePoint Enterprise/Standard Edition 2010. Does someone have a code snippet for this as I have very little time to do this and I can't afford to start coding from the scratch.

Comment: Just a question on the free tool.  Is it a CodePlex solution?  If so, it ma be worth checking the discussions to see if this has been asked before.  It would also be helpful if you could link to the utility too.

Comment: Whats is the name if free tool that does this but it works only for SharePoint Enterprise/Standard Edition 2010?
We can use that one.

Answer (score 2):

No, this can not be done OOB way. May be you can write some java script which will create the excel data.

Comment: -1 OP specifically mentions code, not an OOTB solution

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this by OOTB need to do write some custom code

Comment: -1 OP specifically mentions code, not an OOTB solution